# Writing a function that deals with array of any type

Tags: c, arrays, linux

I came across this question in C:

> Implement the `void arr_mix_x(void *arr, int n, size_t size);`
>   function. The function will mix the elements. It will do so by:
>
> 1. Putting the lower half of the array in the even indexes of the array.
> 2. Putting the higher half of the array in the odd indexes of the array, reversed.
> 3. After doing so, move all elements one left in cycle.

I succeeded with the first part of the question, which was the same, but dealing with `int` arrays only. However, the code I've written (or altered from the first part of the question) is giving me a segmentation fault when I try to run it. This is the code:

```
void arr_mix_x(void *arr, int n, size_t size)
{
    int i, j;
    void *tmpArr = malloc(size);
    void *tmp = NULL;

    memcpy(tmpArr, arr, size);

    for (i = 0, j = n-1; i < n/2; i++, j--)
    {
        memcpy(arr+(i*2), tmpArr+i, size/n);
        memcpy(arr+((i*2)+1), tmpArr+j, size/n);
    }

    memcpy(tmp, arr, size/n);

    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        memcpy(arr+i, arr+i+1, size/n);
    }

    memcpy(arr+n-1, tmp, size/n);

    free(tmpArr);
    tmpArr = NULL;
}
```

And this is the array and the call to the function:

```
int arr[10] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };

arr_mix_x(arr, 10, sizeof(int) * 10);
```

Comment: Pointer arithmetic on `void` pointers is not allowed. Can you tell why?

Comment: The question you cite is nonsensical. There can be no array of `void`, because `void` is not a complete object type.

Comment: Are you allowed to create additional data structures?

Comment: What should `void *tmp = NULL;  memcpy(tmp, arr, size/n);` do?

Comment: `void` arrays (i.e. `void []`) do not exist in C. There is no `void` type, that is just required by the grammar.

Comment: @EOF Edited the title...

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I'm using them for the 3rd part of the question: to move the elements of the array one left.

Comment: @PrestonM Well the question doesn't say anything about using additional data structures, so I suppose it's allowed.

Comment: The way you call your function is wrong, and/or you don't understand the signature of the function. My understanding is, the `size_t` part should be the size of each array element, just like `qsort` standard C library.

Comment: OK, then `tmp` needs to be the address of an area of memory that is `size/n` bytes long.

Comment: @user3528438 It appears you're right. I changed my code so `size` would be the size of each element in the array. It's working now, but the resulting array is completely wrong.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I changed it so it would allocate an area of memory that's `size` bytes long to `tmp` (changed `size` to specify the size of each element). It's working but not as expected.

Comment: `void *arr ... arr+(i*2)` is not well defined code in C.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: It's working now. I posted an answer with the code in case it may help someone with a similar issue.

Comment: @chux Well I'm trying to get to a certain address in memory... It's working now though. You're saying it isn't good practice?

Comment: _Some_ compilers use an extension to the C language and treat `void *` as a pointer to a size 1 object, thus allowing `arr+(i*2)` to work as you hope.  More portable code uses `memcpy((unsigned char *)arr+(i*2), ...` to accomplish that pointer addition.  Even simpler, use `unsigned char *p = arr;` and then `p` in place of `arr` for the rest of code.  Same idea for `tmpArr, tmp`.

Comment: @EOF it means that the calling code may have arrays of various types, but all will use this function to perform the rearrangement of elements

Comment: @chux Thanks a lot for letting me know about this. I'll change my code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I apparently had some errors in the code itself. I changed it and it's working now. Here's the code if it may help anyone having a similar issue:

```
void arr_mix_x(void *arr, int n, size_t size)
{
    int i, j;
    void *tmpArr = malloc(size * n);
    void *tmp = malloc(size);

    memcpy(tmpArr, arr, size * n);

    for (i = 0, j = n-1; i < n/2; i++, j--)
    {
        memcpy(arr+(i*2*size), tmpArr+(i*size), size);
        memcpy(arr+((i*2+1)*size), tmpArr+(j*size), size);
    }

    memcpy(tmp, arr, size);

    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        memcpy(arr+(i*size), arr+((i+1)*size), size);
    }

    memcpy(arr+((n-1)*size), tmp, size);

    free(tmpArr);
    tmpArr = NULL;

    free(tmp);
    tmp = NULL;
}
```

And the function call:

```
arr_mix_x(arr, 10, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Your code is relying on a non-standard compiler extension that allows using `+` on a variable of type `void *`.  In Standard C you should use `char *tmpArr` and you will also need to uses casos when you write `arr+`.

Comment: @M.M Actually I'm using GCC compiler. Thanks for the info, I'll check it out.